# Architecture for website with complex workflow in the background

Tags: web-apps, file-management, cms, self-hosted, workflow

I have been asked to propose a solution for a website with a complex workflow in the background.

Requirement: The website is a document authoring/publishing website which will allow users the upload files (the content plus many auxiliary files such as images, appendix, etc). Once the files are received, a workflow is initiated which involves storing the files, other data, firing jobs, uploading files to ftp, state transitions of the articles - sent to review, reviewed, etc. The other set of users are content reviewers who can download files and upload newer versions along with comments.

Solution must have:

1. The website must support 1000 concurrent users.
2. Technologies and components chosen should be reusable/extendable as necessary for other enterprise applications.
3. Responsive web UI so as to support mobile devices as well
4. Ability to handle files to the tune of 5-10 MB
5. The file storage could grow exponentially and should support data to the tune of 2-5 TB

Good to have:

1. Archiving mechanism in the file storage

The solution can be either Microsoft/Java/open source or a mix of all these technologies.

Technologies being considered:

1. Website : ASP.Net MVC, JSP, open source frameworks such as bootstrap/angular/foundation
2. Workflow engine: Windows Workflow foundation, Java workflow tooling,
3. Database : SQL Server, MySQL, Mongo
4. Document storage: Sharepoint, good old folders

I am from the Microsoft background and don't have much exposure to the Java/Open source world. I'd appreciate any input from those who have created similar applications.